# Evaluate YAML elements with ERB syntax

Tags: ruby, yaml, erb

I have a YAML which includes some ERB blocks:

```
---
- id: "1"
  pre: |
     <%
     a = rand(2..20)
     b = rand(1..20)
     %>
  sentence: "The result of <%=a%> + <%=b%> is <%=a+b%>"
- id: "2"
  pre: |
     <%
     a = rand(1..20)
     b = 5
     %>
  sentence: "The fraction $\frac{<%=a%>}{<%=b%>}$ equals to $<%=Rational(a, b)%>$"
[many more]
---
```

I want to get element `N`, evaluate as ERB template and return as `YAML` string

Example: if we get element `1`, I expected to get:

```
---
- id: "1"
  pre: |

  sentence: "The result of 3 + 4 is 7"
---
```

Comment: You could pass the whole YAML file / string through ERB.

Comment: @Stefan But this wastes a lot of time. I just want to evaluate just some elements of YAML structure. Not whole file

Comment: And you need to generate a new YAML structure containing just those elements afterwards?